# Math equation generator program

Tags: python

When I run this code, the part where the program asks for a difficulty level keeps repeating. How can I solve the problem?

```
import random
import time
import sys


correct = 0  #Amount the user has gotten correct
ans = 0 #Holds the answer to the question
lastName = str()   #holds last name
firstName = str()   #holds first name
className = str()    #holds user's form
difficulty = int() #where user input what diffliculty they want
Beginner = 0 
beginner = 0
Intermediate = 0
intermediate = 0
Advanced = 0
advanced = 0

F = firstName = raw_input("Please enter your first name: ").title()
L = lastName = raw_input("Please enter your surname: ").title()
C = className = raw_input("Please enter your form class: ").title()
print "Hi", F, L, 
print ''

time.sleep(1)

while True:
    difficulty = int(input("Please select a difficulty level: Beginner, Intermediate, or Advanced: "))
    
if difficulty == "Beginner":
    def multiplication(): #Creates a multiplication question in beginner 
        global ans
        numOne, numTwo = random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)
        print "What is", numOne, "*" , numTwo, "?"
        ans = (numOne*numTwo)

    def addition(): #Creates a addition question in beginner 
        global ans
        numOne, numTwo = random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)
        print "What is", numOne, "+" , numTwo, "?"
        ans = (numOne+numTwo)

    def subtraction(): #Creates a subtraction question in beginner 
        global ans
        numOne, numTwo = random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)
        print "What is", numOne, "-" , numTwo, "?"
        ans = (numOne-numTwo)
        
operation = [multiplication,subtraction,addition]   #holds all of the opperators
randOperation = random.choice(operation)    #chooses a random operator

if difficulty == "Intermediate":
    def multiplication(): #Creates a multiplication question in intermediate 
        global ans
        numOne, numTwo = random.randint(10,20), random.randint(10,20)
        print "What is", numOne, "*" , numTwo, "?"
        ans = (numOne*numTwo)

    def addition(): #Creates a addition question in intermediate
        global ans
        numOne, numTwo = random.randint(10,20), random.randint(10,20)
        print "What is", numOne, "+" , numTwo, "?"
        ans = (numOne+numTwo)

    def subtraction():#Creates a subtraction question in intermediate 
        global ans
        numOne, numTwo = random.randint(10,20), random.randint(10,20)
        print "What is", numOne, "-" , numTwo, "?"
        ans = (numOne-numTwo)
        
operation = [multiplication,subtraction,addition]   #holds all of the opperators
randOperation = random.choice(operation)    #chooses a random operator

if difficulty == "Advanced":
    def multiplication(): #Creates a multiplication question in advanced 
        global ans
        numOne, numTwo = random.randint(20,35), random.randint(20,35)
        print "What is", numOne, "*" , numTwo, "?"
        ans = (numOne*numTwo)

    def addition(): #Creates a addition in advanced  
        global ans
        numOne, numTwo = random.randint(20,35), random.randint(20,35)
        print "What is", numOne, "+" , numTwo, "?"
        ans = (numOne+numTwo)

    def subtraction(): #Creates a subtraction question in advanced
        global ans
        numOne, numTwo = random.randint(20,35), random.randint(20,35)
        print "What is", numOne, "-" , numTwo, "?"
        ans = (numOne-numTwo)
        
operation = [multiplication,subtraction,addition]   #holds all of the opperators
randOperation = random.choice(operation)    #chooses a random operator


def main():   #main game loop - ask questions and checks it against answer, stops are a give amount of questions
    question = 0
    user_score = 0
    randOperation = random.choice(operation)

    while True:
        try:
            randOperation()
            randOperation = random.choice(operation)
            if question >= 12:
                break
            userInput = int(input("Enter the answer: "))
            if userInput == ans:
                print("Correct!" + "\n")
                user_score += 1
                question += 1
            else:
                print("Incorrect!" + "\n")
                question += 1
        except ValueError:
            print("I'm sorry that's invalid")
            question += 1

main()    #initializes the function

print(firstName, lastName , "you scored" , user_score , "out of 10")   #shows the user's score and name

user_name = firstName + ' ' + lastName
function(user_score,user_name)


def endMenu():
    while True:
        try:  
            options = int(input('''Press '1' to view users' scores,
            press '2' to restart the test,
            press '3' to exit the game,

            Enter option here: '''))
        except ValueError:
            print("I'm sorry that was invalid...")

        if options == 3:  #exits the game...
            sys.exit()

        elif options == 2:   #starts the game loop again because it's in a function
            main()

        elif options == 1:   #displays everything on the .txt file
            f = open('userScore.txt', 'r')
            print(f.read())
            print()
            endMenu()

        else:
            print("Sorry, I don't understand. Please try again...")
            print()
            endMenu()        

endMenu()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the `input()` statement to obtain the difficulty level in an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    difficulty = int(input("Please select a difficulty level: Beginner, Intermediate, or Advanced: "))
```

Just get rid of the loop:

```
difficulty = int(input("Please select a difficulty level: Beginner, Intermediate, or Advanced: "))
```

It is unclear what the user is supposed to enter in response to this prompt. It looks like you want then to enter an integer, but the prompt suggests that one of the strings "Beginner", "Intermediate", or "Advanced" should be entered. The rest of your code also expects one of these strings, so you should change your `input()` statement to:

```
difficulty = raw_input("Please select a difficulty level: Beginner, Intermediate, or Advanced: ")
```

If you want to validate the user input before proceeding, you can do it in a loop like this:

```
difficulty_levels = ['Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Advanced']
difficulty = None
while difficulty not in difficulty_levels:
    difficulty = raw_input("Please select a difficulty level: Beginner, Intermediate, or Advanced: ")
```

Comment: Probably slightly better to use `difficulty_levels = {'Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Advanced'}` and make it a set.

Comment: I've sorted out the difficulty level now but it wont ask any questions when you enter beginner, intermediate or advanced. would you have any idea why it is doing that? and how could you fix it?.

Comment: Without seeing the revised code, no. You should ask another question, but try to minimise the amount of code you post in that question; keep it to the minimum amount of code required to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This loop will never, ever end...:

```
while True:
    difficulty = int(input("Please select a difficulty level: Beginner, Intermediate, or Advanced: "))
```

Presumably you're looking for something like:

```
while True:
    try:
        difficulty = int(input("Please select a difficulty level: Beginner, Intermediate, or Advanced: "))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        if 0 <= difficulty <= 2: break
    print('Please enter 0, 1, or 2')
```

Comment: While this will avoid the infinite loop, it also allows the `difficulty` variable to be set to an integer value, which is incompatible with the rest of the code — a detail I think would have been worth at least pointing out even though the OP didn't mention the issue (and the fact that there are also number of other ones). Just my 2₤.

Comment: Considering the `difficulty = int(...` it's hard to miss that `difficulty` **will** be set to an `int` and thus never equal a string -- when posted code has, say, 37 bugs, how many should one point out in an answer?-)  As the OP singled out the "it keeps on repeating" issue I chose to specifically address that one out of the 37...:-)